# Can't use any options in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I can't use any keyboard shortcuts. I can't copy, paste, zoom in and out.
When I right click on text, all the options are gray.

Comment: What VS version are you using? Can you perhaps add a few steps-to-reproduce details, maybe screenshots?

Comment: Any chance your trial or license has expired? Check the account window.

Comment: Try opening the installer program and repair VS.